# Will search engines try to follow a javascript type of address link?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have the following on my page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doCheck('test'); return false;" class="btn">Test</a>
```

It works great but now I'm wondering what will happen when it is seen by a search engine. Will the search engine try to click the address and follow it?

Comment: Hardly, seeing as it's not really leading anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Google will just ignore it.

It's bad practice to use onClick in that way though, and using the void statement is pretty horrible too.

Have a look at [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice/5871737#5871737) for an explanation of why.

Comment: That is not exactly true, the Googlebot has basic ability to execute JavaScript.  So while I totally agree that it is a horribly bad practice, if Googlebot doesn't yet have the ability to do this they will in the future.

Comment: This particular link will be ignored, if my assumptions about it running some check and updating a small section of the page are correct.

Comment: You are right if it doesn't redirect, but if it does then Google might use it.  The user really didn't specify, so it is up in the air I guess.